# Cordova Binary File Upload

Tags: java, android, cordova, upload

I am trying to POST a binary file to a webserver using Cordova. I am using the [File Transfer](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/) object to do so, and it works as expected on iOS. When I try it on Android, however, the binary file POSTed by the app is roughly double the size. When I open the POSTed file in a hex editor, I can see that the file is riddled with `EF BF BD` over and over.

This led me to the following [SO Article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10671336/zip-file-modified-when-added-to-phonegap-app) which leads me to believe it is strictly an Android alignment issue.

The problem is, I still can't figure out how to do a basic binary file upload using Cordova under Android. How would one go about doing it?

Any tips?